# How to get results greater than yesterday

Tags: mysql

I have a database that stores the date for each entry with the DATETIME format. I need to only retrieve results that are greater than yesterday. I say yesterday because I need the results for the current day and forward.

Currently I have the following.

`$yest = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-1,  date("Y"));`
`$yest_date = date('n-j-o', $yest);`

`SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME WHERE DATE_FORMAT(event_date, \"%c-%d-%Y\") > '".$yest_date."'`

That does not give any results even though I know there are events. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

`SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE event_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: This won't work since it does not remove the time part. Yesterday is very probaly starting at `00:00:00`, not at `NOW() - 1`

Answer (score 8):

```
WHERE event_date > date(now()) - 1
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Select * from tbl_name WHERE event_date > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This should have it start from the beginning of yesterday rather than 24hours back from the time the query is run.

If you have this run in a cron you should probably verify the timezone of the database vs the server so that you don't run it for two days back intending to run at 12:01 but actually running at 11:01 due to variance.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME WHERE event_date >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE field_date > now()- interval 1 day;
```

Answer (score 0):

what this one does is to select values from the first minute today until last minute today.

```
WHERE scheduled_start_timestamp >= date() AND scheduled_start_timestamp <= date() + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME WHERE DATE_FORMAT > CAST(GETDATE() -1 AS DATE)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).